# Independent random selection with replacement of elements per column in a matrix

Tags: matlab, random, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` which is of size `r1 x c`.  I'm trying to create a matrix `B` which is of size `r2 x c` where for each individual column, I would like to randomly sample with replacement.

I wrote this code that does what I am looking for:

```
%// Define a random index : 
RO = randi(r1,r2,c);

%// Define an output matrix
B = zeros(r2,c);

%// Perform selection        
for i1 = 1:c
    for i2 = 1:r2
        B(i2,i1) = A(RO(i2,i1),i1);
    end
end
```

Is there an easier and/or faster way to do this in MATLAB without loops?

Comment: Given a matrix A, you want to: (1) randomly rearrange the columns subject to the constraint that (2) every column *cannot* remain in its original position?  (Note: constraint (2) strikes me as somewhat strange + tricky... but I have no idea what's the application)

Comment: "sorting" and "replacement" sound contradictory to me

Comment: So did my answer help you?

Comment: Hello @rayryeng, thanks for you help.I don't run your code yet, but I think it's the code that I need.

Comment: No problem. When you're ready, consider accepting my answer to let everyone know you no longer need help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am interpreting this code correctly, you have a matrix and for each column, you consider this to be an individual signal and you want to randomly sample `r2` elements from each signal to create another `r2` signal that possibly has duplicates.  You wish to stack these columns horizontally to generate an output matrix.  A property with this matrix is that for each column, this random sampling is applied only for the corresponding column in the input matrix.

You can certainly do this vectorized.  The matrix `RO` would be used as row coordinates and the column coordinates, which we will call `RC`, would simply be matrix of enumerations where each row is the linear range `1:c` and there are `r2` of these stacked on top of each other.  This can be achieved with [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

First obtain the linear indices of the row and column coordinates via [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) then use this to index into your input matrix `A`.

```
RO = randi(r1,r2,c);
RC = repmat(1:c,r2,1);
ind = sub2ind(size(A), RO, RC);
B = A(ind);
```

---

To show that this works, I've created the following data:

```
rng(123);
r1 = 5;
r2 = 10;
c = 3;
A = randi(10, r1, c);
```

Running your code above gives me:

```
>> B

B =

     6    10     8
     7    10     5
     7    10     4
     3    10     4
     3     5     5
     6     5     1
     8     7     4
     6     7     8
     6     7     5
     6     7     4
```

Using the same matrix `RO` that was generated, the more optimized code that I wrote also gives:

```
>> B

B =

     6    10     8
     7    10     5
     7    10     4
     3    10     4
     3     5     5
     6     5     1
     8     7     4
     6     7     8
     6     7     5
     6     7     4
```